# Overlapping bars with BokehJS bar graph

Tags: javascript, client-side, bokeh

I'd like to make a plot like the one shown below using BokehJS.

Specifically, I have two data series that share x-labels and I want to make a bar graph showing each in a different color (simple enough).  But style-wise, I would like one bar to be narrower than the other, while they both share the same centers on the x-axis.  For visibility's sake, the wider bars should be shown "behind" the narrower bars.

Moreover, I'd like to make it using purely BokehJS, rather than using the Python interface.  I can't find any examples with this styling.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Oh!  One last thing: ideally, I'd like to be able to update this graph on the fly using javascript.  So say at the beginning of the exercise, my data is in a javascript variable, but I have alternate data in another javascript variable (with the same structure).  I'd like to be able to update the data and have the graph re-render on the client side.  Worst case, I know how to write enough JS to totally tear-down the Bokeh plot and redraw it from scratch when I need to update.  But I have to imagine there is a way to simply inject the new numerical data and tell the Bokeh plot to update itself.  But perhaps I'm too optimistic?

[image: Bar chart with overlapping bars]

Answer (score 0):

Use `bokeh.plotting.vbar` and set the width to a smaller value when plotting the second dataset.

Comment: See the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491172/how-to-draw-categorical-bar-plot-using-vbar-method-in-bokeh-plotting-module?rq=1 for an example of plotting with vbar.  In that answer the width is constant and only only one dataset is plotted.  Plotting the second should be straight-forward.